# Google Tag Error

Tags: php, cs-cart

Hello I've installed the Google Tag

```
design/themes/[YOUR THEME]/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/index/main_content.pre.tpl
```

Everything is fine except Google Tag Assistant give me the following error

```
<script> tag must not be included in a <div>
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: `script` element should be inside `<head>` in the header of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the file to content.pre.tpl

Also please make sure the document looks like this:

```
{literal}
google tag manager code
{/literal}
```

Comment: Have you renamed the file?

Comment: After this enter your store as follows: "store.com/adminurl.php?cc&ctpl

Comment: Please try disabling and re-enabling your "my-changes" addon

Comment: Just a recommendation but you might want to take a look into Google's enhanced ecommerce (as google tag manager isnt used that much in cs-cart)